# Is there a way to optimize g++ so that it build faster?

Tags: c++, g++

**Note: this has absolutely nothing to do with optimization of produced binary code.**

I have a project with more than 120 source code files. If I put everything into one huge cpp file, the compilation of the code take significantly shorter than running standard makefile build which spawn separate g++ process for every single cpp file. (I also noticed that running g++ on cpp file which is nearly empty, or empty at all, takes also some time, so running g++ on 2 cpp files that are relatively small takes significantly longer than running it on 1 cpp file that contains the code of both).

Given the size of the project, the compilation currently takes long time even on very fast hardware. Is there anything that could be done in order to speed up the time it takes for compiler to produce binary file? Given that g++ process is loaded for every cpp file with same options, I assume it is doing lot of same work for every file (it surely needs to load something from some libraries, etc, check same things over and over again and so on). Isn't there something that could make it skip doing the "same tasks repeatedly for every file" so that it produces the object files much faster?

EDIT: The project is Qt application, Makefile is generated using `qmake`

Comment: If you only have 120 cpp files to compile, how long do you consider to be "long"?

Comment: Try precompiled headers. You noticed that two files are compiled longer than one - this might be because each of your source files includes one or more headers. So you compile not only your source file but also all its includes. If there are some common files in include list of both source files then you double job. Precompiled headers can mitigate this issue. There are some other reasons for slow down - for instance, reading one file from disk is faster than two files with the same combined contents.

Comment: If you combine files, then when only one line is changed, the entire project must be rebuilt.  Are you using a *make* system such as CMake?

Comment: How do you manage the build? Handwritten makefile? CMake? AutoMake? Sounds like you are not exploiting parallel builds nor incremental builds... Please provide more details.

Comment: The quickest, cheapest fixes are using precompiled headers and getting rid of any unnecessary includes. Forward declare whenever possible. The next step is a shiny SSD and some RAM.

Comment: 120 source files is not a huge project. It is a *small* project. Having separate compilation units does impose an extra cost for that initial build. That extra cost pays for itself in short order when you change but a small number of files and need to rebuild.

Comment: You might want to look into Pimpl aka Compiler Firewall to speed up the compilation. http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm

Answer (score 2):

Did you try parallel compilation? You can add -jN flags to make, where N is number of compilation threads (usually 1.5 * number of cpu cores).

Comment: I think that you are confusing `gcc` with `make`

Comment: Oh yes, this is a very useful suggestion at some point, I know about this and it indeed speeds things up, but it really is more about running multiple instances of g++ instead of making its execution more effective

Comment: I think that in order to compile 120+ files, make (or equivalent tool) is used, so for me it's normal to give a suggestion about this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can try:

- Make sure that you aren't including every header in every source file, try to minimize coupling between files.
- Utilize precompiled headers t o avoid reading system headers over and over.
- Include related sets of `.C` files in `.cxx` files, which you then compile with your makefile. This has the effect of putting all the source in one file without making the code harder to read.

Comment: Forward declare classes instead of including the header files. The PIMPL idiom might also come in handy to minimize dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a cache for `gcc` that I know of is [`ccache`](http://ccache.samba.org/), you can use it when invoking `gcc` itself like so

```
ccache gcc [...]
```

But I would suggest you to switch to a building system such as `make` or `cmake` because this softwares are able to track dependencies and files that don't need to be re-compiled again.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to do :

- when possible, forward declare in headers, instead of including headers
- remove not needed includes
- instead of using qmake and makefile, use cmake and ninja (see [this](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#gen%3aNinja))
- get better hardware (ssd disk, more and faster memory, CPUs, ... )
- spawn more jobs when building

---

> If I put everything into one huge cpp file, the compilation of the code take significantly shorter than running standard makefile build which spawn separate g++ process for every single cpp file.

Most likely the culprit is bad hard disk. By getting a super fast ssd disk, you are going to see huge improvements.

Comment: I actually have SSD on one of my laptops and it doesn't really seem to be so much utilized, usually it's CPU that is 100% used, while IO is rather low. But on other hand I have very slow CPU there, around 1.2 GHZ